# How to add 2nd street-line in google contacts StructuredPostalAddres (GData)

Tags: java, gdata, google-contacts-api

After reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/extensions/package-summary) and [Google's developer guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#creating_contacts), I did not find a to add a second address line.

For example, if I want to store this address as a Google contact : 

Mr. Ace Person 

Amphitheatre Village Premium Outlets

1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy

Mountain View CA 94043 

I can add the street as demonstrated in the developer guide :

```
StructuredPostalAddress postalAddress = new StructuredPostalAddress();
postalAddress.setStreet(new Street("1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy"));
```

I couldn't find a structured solution to add a "2 line street address".

Obviously I could add one of the two lines as a house-name (setHousename(housename)) or Neighborhood (setNeighborhood(neighborhood)) but this is not quiet right.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no document or feature that support what you want to accomplish. According to the current [document](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?csw=1#schema_93) pertaining to the [element's property](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?csw=1#properties_94) which you can choose what appropriate property to work around you 2nd street line. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess I will have to go for  a workaround . +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no document or feature that support what you want to accomplish. According to the current [document](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?csw=1#schema_93) pertaining to the [element's property](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?csw=1#properties_94) which you can choose what appropriate property to work around you 2nd street line. I hope it helps.